# Magento mirgration issue

Tags: migration

I want these attribute data in my magento website.

when i delete these sourcce model it work fine but who can i change the source model value.

I dont want to ignore these attributes. If you have any other solution please comment below

```
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_CATALOG_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 477 from `catalog_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 477 from `catalog_product_entity_int`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 467,477 from `eav_entity_attribute`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class profile/entity_school is not mapped in record attribute_id=551
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class eav/entity_attribute_source_custom is not mapped in record attribute_id=563
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class shipperhq_shipper/source_freight_freightclass is not mapped in record attribute_id=614
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class wsafedexfreight/shipping_carrier_wsafedexfreight_source_freightclass is not mapped in record attribute_id=620
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class wsafedexfreight/shipping_carrier_wsafedexfreight_source_itempackaging is not mapped in record attribute_id=621
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class boxmenu/boxmenu is not mapped in record attribute_id=627
[2020-02-25 06:33:46][ERROR]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class shipperhq_shipper/source_validation_result is not mapped in record attribute_id=666
```